# How to skip some test folder when running rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task, rake-test

I have the following configuration for running tests of a gem:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << 'lib'
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.pattern = 'test/**/*_test.rb'
  t.verbose = false
end
```

inside my `test` folder I have a folder (let's say `skipped_tests`) with tests which I don't want to test with this task.
Is it possible to adjust pattern  to skip particular folder, something like the following:

```
t.pattern = 'test/^skipped_tests/*_test.rb'
```

Please share your thoughts on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `test_files` instead of `pattern` like this:

```
t.test_files = Dir['test/**/*_test.rb'].reject do |path| 
  path.include?('skipped_test')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `FileList` with the `test_files` attribute.  It may be more concise (and/or precise) than performing the reject manually.

So the OP's example would become:

```rb
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << 'lib'
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.test_files = FileList['test/**/*_test.rb'].exclude('test/skipped_tests/**/*')
  t.verbose = false
end
```